# Flurry no longer allows to create and use analytics for Windows Phone apps?

Tags: windows-phone, analytics, flurry, mobile-analytics

I have been using Flurry analytics for Windows Phone apps for 3 years. Today I wanted to use it in my new app. When I pressed "Add a New Application", I didn't see an option to select Windows Phone platform (it was definitely there several months ago).
[image]

What happened? Did Flurry terminate adding new Windows Phone apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately they did after they were bought by Yahoo

Answer (score 2):

You can still access them by URL.

Just take the Windows Phone URI:
https://dev.flurry.com/createProjectSelectPlatform.do?platformName=windowsPhone

remove “Phone”
https://dev.flurry.com/createProjectSelectPlatform.do?platformName=windows
and it will work!

My old apps are still working too.

See this [blog](http://www.rudyhuyn.com/blog/2014/10/21/use-flurry-on-a-windows-8-app/) post